# Type variables in context not fixed?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, hlist

I'm currently experimenting with typelevel code. I've got one instance with a type variable that only occurs in the context, and not in the instance itself. Somehow the compiler doesn't like that, but I can't figure out why not. Adding a functional dependency to `HasRecipe` `effect pot target -> deps` works for that error, but then the incorrect `deps` are inferred at the test in the last line of the code.

Error:

```
• Could not deduce (HasRecipe target pot effect deps0)
  from the context: (HasRecipe target pot effect deps,
                     SubSelect pot deps)
    bound by an instance declaration:
               forall target (pot :: [*]) (effect :: * -> *) (deps :: [*]).
               (HasRecipe target pot effect deps, SubSelect pot deps) =>
               CanCook target pot effect
    at Lib.hs:15:10-92
  The type variable ‘deps0’ is ambiguous
• In the ambiguity check for an instance declaration
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  In the instance declaration for ‘CanCook target pot effect’
```

Source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-11.4 --install-ghc runghc
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Proxy

class HEq (x :: k) (y :: k) (b :: Bool) | x y -> b

data family HList (l::[*])

data instance HList '[] = HNil
data instance HList (x ': xs) = x `HCons` HList xs

deriving instance Eq (HList '[])
deriving instance (Eq x, Eq (HList xs)) => Eq (HList (x ': xs))

deriving instance Ord (HList '[])
deriving instance (Ord x, Ord (HList xs)) => Ord (HList (x ': xs))

deriving instance Bounded (HList '[])
deriving instance (Bounded x, Bounded (HList xs)) => Bounded (HList (x ': xs))

class HExtend e l where
  type HExtendR e l
  (.*.) :: e -> l -> HExtendR e l

infixr 2 .*.

instance HExtend e (HList l) where
  type HExtendR e (HList l) = HList (e ': l)
  (.*.) = HCons


main = pure ()

newtype Recipe effect target (deps :: [*]) = Recipe { runRecipe :: HList deps -> effect target }

class CanCook target (pot :: [*]) effect | pot -> effect where
  cook :: HList pot -> effect target

instance (HasRecipe target pot effect deps, SubSelect pot deps) => CanCook target pot effect where
  cook pot =
    let
      deps :: HList deps
      deps = subselect pot
      r :: Recipe effect target deps
      r = recipe pot
    in
      runRecipe r $ deps

type family PotEffect (pot :: [*]) where
  PotEffect (Recipe effect _ _ ': '[]) = effect
  PotEffect (Recipe effect _ _ ': tail) = effect

class HasRecipe target (pot :: [*]) effect deps | pot -> effect where
  recipe :: HList pot -> Recipe effect target deps

class SubSelect (pot :: [*]) (deps :: [*]) where
  subselect :: HList pot -> HList deps

instance SubSelect t f where
  subselect = undefined

class HasRecipeCase (b :: Bool) (target :: *) (pot :: [*]) effect (deps :: [*]) | pot -> effect where
  recipeCase :: Proxy b -> Proxy target -> HList pot -> Recipe effect target deps

instance HasRecipeCase True target ((Recipe effect target deps) ': leftoverPot) effect deps where
  recipeCase _ _ (HCons head _) = head

instance (HasRecipe target leftoverPot effect deps) =>
  HasRecipeCase False target ((Recipe effect target1 deps) ': leftoverPot) effect deps where
  recipeCase _ _ (HCons _ tail) = recipe tail

instance (HEq target t bool, HasRecipeCase bool target pot effect deps, pot ~ ((Recipe effect t deps) ': leftoverPot)) =>
  HasRecipe target ((Recipe effect t deps) ': leftoverPot) effect deps where
  recipe = undefined

newtype M1 = M1 ()
newtype M2 = M2 ()
newtype M3 = M3 ()
newtype M4 = M4 ()

r1 :: Recipe IO M1 '[M2, M3]
r1 = undefined

r2 :: Recipe IO M2 '[]
r2 = undefined

r3 :: Recipe IO M3 '[M4]
r3 = undefined

r4 :: Recipe IO M4 '[]
r4 = undefined

cookbook1 = r1 .*. r2 .*. r3 .*. r4 .*. HNil

cookbook2 = r3 .*. r4 .*. r2 .*. r1 .*. HNil

c1 = cook cookbook1 :: IO M4
-- c2 = cook cookbook2 :: IO M4
```

Comment: What happens if you enable ambiguous types?

Comment: Same error, but at the caller site.

Comment: shouldn't `SubSelect` have some instances? Otherwise it's not constraining anything.

Comment: I can't even try to run this example: there's no package `hlist` in `lts-11.4`. What dependencies are you using? `multistate` has `Data.HList.HList` and is in `lts-11.4`, for instance. Are you using that one?

Comment: @chi sorry, worked here because I did it as a project and exported it as a stack script :-/ . It should be `HList-0.5.0.0`

Comment: Unless there's some part of the code you haven't shown, `DefaultRecipe` is useless because `def` can never be implemented.

Comment: The script is now without external dependencies and produces the mentioned error. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an instance like this

```
instance (HasRecipe target pot effect deps, SubSelect pot deps)
       => CanCook target pot effect where
```

The tyvar `deps` appears in the context, but not in the head, making the instance ambiguous.

Concretely, it could be possible to have four instances

```
instance HasRecipe target pot effect A
instance SubSelect pot A
instance HasRecipe target pot effect B
instance SubSelect pot B
```

and GHC has no way to select which one you want. You have to choose `deps` either at instance definition, or (enabling ambiguous types) at the `cook` call site.

If there were a fundep such as `target pot effect -> deps` this would remove the ambiguity, but it is hard for me to understand the intent.